# como hago para que mi array sea de el tamaño que introduzco en un input y haya una posición 0?

Tags: javascript, html5, array, while

bueno en resumen lo que quiero hacer es mediante un input darle tamaño a un vector array, luego que ya tenga el tamaño del vector array mediante lo introducido previamente en mi input, poder introducir números en esas posiciones array y esos números poder verificar si son pares o impares y luego imprimirlos en un `<h1>` en un html (**obligada mente tengo que usar while y un array**) .

mi problema es que si introduzco en mi input que el tamaño del array es: ejemplo "2" el prompt me muestra un array de mas, ejemplo: si introduje 2 el para darle tamaño al array, inicia de 0 a 2 entonces serian 3 números  (0-1-2) como puedo evitar eso? muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```js
function parinpar(){
    var tamanioarray = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('cantidad')[0].value);
    var x = 0;
    var ingresado;
    var array_dato = [tamanioarray];  //x tiene que ser menor que el vector array
    var pares =0;
    var inpares =0;
    while(x < tamanioarray){
        var tamanio = parseInt(prompt('ingrese numeros a comparar' + x));
        if(tamanio % 2 == 0 ){
            alert("es par")          
            pares++
        }else{
            alert("es impar")
            inpares++
        }
    x++
    
    }
   
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = tamanioarray;
    document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = pares;
    document.getElementById('impar').innerHTML = inpares;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Par o impar </title>
        <script src="work js/parinpar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <label for="">ingrese cuantos Numeros quiere comprobar si son par/impar (recuerde que array inicia desde 0)</label>
            <input type="number" name="cantidad">
            <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="parinpar()">
        </form>
        <h1 id="yax">cuantos numeros introdujo + 0</h1>
        <h1 id="res">numeros introdusidos</h1>
        <h1 id="yax">cuantos son pares</h1>
        <h1 id="par">son los pares</h1>
        <h1 id="yax">cuantos son inpares</h1>
        <h1 id="impar">son los impares</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

muchas gracias por leer, apenas si tengo como 3 clases en Javascript y no se mucho perdón si el problema es obvio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La longitud de los  arreglos se cuenta empezando en 1. Por eso un arreglo que tenga capacidad para 2 elementos tendrá una longitud igual a 2.

Los elementos que se guardan dentro del arreglo se empieza a guardar en la posición 0, por eso en un arreglo de longitud 2 el último elemento está en la posición 1 al contar desde cero, o sea, [0]= elemento 1, = [1] elemento 2.

Al usar estructuras de repetición para recorrer un arreglo, la variable que sirve de contador debe iniciar en 0 lo que equivale a la primera posición del arreglo y debe terminar con el valor [tamaño del arreglo] -1.

En tu código el problema es que la condición del while es `x <= tamanioarray`. Si X empieza en cero entonces contará: 0,1,2.

Corrígelo y coloca `x < tamanioArray`;

Comment: entonces por que ```if( x <= tamanioarray )``` tiene una longitud mas larga?

Comment: En ese caso no tiene que ver con longitud si no con una comparación. Con el operador `<=` la condición devuelve verdadero si el valor de la izquierda es menor o igual al de la derecha. Ejemplo las  dos comparaciones: `2 <= 3 y 3 <= 3` son verdaderas, dos resultados verdaderos. Pero si en lugar de `<=` se usa `<` entonces: `2 < 3` es verdadero y `3 < 3` es falso, solo una es verdadera porque el 3 no se incluye.